# I installed IIS 6 after .Net framework and now I dont have "Web service extension" part in IIS 6 win xp

Tags: asp.net, iis-6

I have been programming .NET for 2 years now, but I have never came up with such problem.

The last thing I installed on this fresh Windows XP machine was the IIS. Now when I go to the management console, I do not see web service extensions anywhere. I have tried `aspnet_regiis` from every .NET version installed, but so far no good came out of it.

I still have a very cheap IIS management console, which does not even handle a routine ASP.NET test page.

So, does anyone can help me with this symptom?

*** To make story short: I do not have web service entensions part in my IIS 6 management console ***

I do not know if is normal or not, because I have never tried Windows XP IIS. I have always worked with Windows 2003.

Any idea or suggestions is appreciated.

Comment: So in the end, I noticed the problem was in fact the windows XP IIS, if you had the same problem, just change to another OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that : (FOR IIS6)

> To enable Web service extensions

- .1 In IIS Manager, click the Web Service Extensions folder.
- .2 In the details pane, select the Web service extension that you want to enable, and then click Allow.
- .3 To see the properties of a Web service extension, select an extension, and then click Properties.

source : http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/596ff388-bc4c-472f-b029-aea2b0418bea.mspx?mfr=true

and there is another manual here : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/328419

But ... 
for IIS 5.1 there are no Web Service Extensions in IIS and it is not possible to install IIS 6 to XP.

Comment: Sorry Please refer to the picture I attached, cuz I think you misunderstood me. I DONT HAVE THE WEB SERVICE PART... :(

Comment: so is it IIS 5.1 or IIS 6 ? because there are no Web Service Extensions in IIS 5.1 (winXP default)

Comment: Also seems like it is not possible to install IIS 6 to XP